# Multiple AJAXed tabs

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-tools

I am using
http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/ajax-history.html but when I add multiple ul "css-tabs" classes only the first one works, how can you make it work with multiple classes and support loading any clicked links in to "css-panes"?

Answer (score 0):

Might need some more information, maybe some sample code. Right off the bat it sounds like you might have an issue with an `id` vs `class` property. Often times if you're attempting to select everything with the same `id`, you'll only get the first one on the page. You'd wanna use a `class` attribute if that's the case.

Comment: Thats the issue. I'm already using the class properly like in the page I linked to

Comment: I still don't think I quite understand what you're trying to do. But it would seem you need to change your jQuery to reflect whatever new classes you make. ie. `$("ul.css-tabs-2").tabs( "div.css-panes-2 > div", {effect: 'ajax', history: true} );` Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to add multiple menus in different locations in the file. Every menu has different links

Comment: It sounds like you need to make more `ul` and `div` tags to represent more tabbed panes. These all need to have different `class` attributes: `css-tabs-1`, `css-tabs-2`, `css-panes-1`, and so on. Then point the jQuery to the different class names: `$("ul.css-tabs-2").tabs("div.css-panes-2 > div")` and so on. If that still doesn't answer your question, please be more specific in describing your problem.

Comment: I have one two menus  **<ul class="smenu">
<li><a href="main.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
<li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
</ul>** and **<ul class="smenu2"><li><a href="tos.html">Terms of use</a></li><li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li><li><a href="about.html">About</a></li><li><a href="etc.html">ETC</a></li>
</ul>** If I rename smenu2 to smenu it  doesn't work.

Comment: It also doesn't work if I add     **$(function() {
        $("ul.smenu2").tabs(
        "div#featured",
        {effect: 'ajax', history: true}
      );
      });** In the file

Comment: Anyone? I am still stuck with this problem